# one of the pages doesnt inherit the css form the base

Tags: html, css, django

Hey, I am using django template. what below is a snippet from the base html file, I invoked css link

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="static/css/layout.css"/>
```

but the weirdest thing happened.

```
{% extends "Layout.html" %}
```

all the html pages inherit from the base html file, but there is one page that doesnt inherit the css style while others work perfectly. anyone could think of a possible answer? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Narrow it down.  First, temporarily remove all HTML out of the page that has problems, except the piece of HTML that is not getting the style.  Second, comment out any CSS on the *child* page.  Now, you should not see the problem any more.  So start commenting things back in one by one until you find the problem.

Comment: Is this page on a sub path... e.g.: `http://example.com/sub-category/page-with-no-css/` and all the rest working are based off of '/'?  If so, then your href tag should start with a '/' in the path. Also might to look at the context processors for STATIC_URL and MEDIA_URL .

Comment: Check out the source of the page and see if the the css is linked. If it is, follow the link and make sure that the correct file is loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't hard code your css paths, if you are using the Django 1.3 `staticfiles` app, set the following in your `settings.py`:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

In your template:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/layout.css"/>
```

I'm assuming that `css/layout.css` is present in the `static` folder of one of your app.

Comment: OMG! It Works! but how come it didnt work, this is before ("static/css/layout.css"), this is now (/static/css/layout.css), I guess the reason is that the url I am trying to map is user/userexample while others are /user Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible reason.  This:

```
href="static/css/layout.css"
```

is relative to the current page.  So if works for this URL:

```
http://mysite.com/page
```

then it will fail for this one:

```
http://mysite.com/subdirectory/deeper
```

You need to prefix the `href` with `/` (or the base URL of the site).

Comment: I have tried to add /, but it doesnt seem to work...Thank you